# How to manage mime data received from a drop event

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Consider a typical way of dealing with a drop event in Qt, where my widget inspects the mime data contained in the drop event and then acts accordingly:

```
void MyWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    // check if the event mime data is the kind this widget can process
    if(event->mimeData()->hasUrls()) {
        event->acceptProposedAction();
        const QMimeData* mData = event->mimeData();
        // process data...
    }

}
```

Suppose `MyWidget` is some dummy UI element and I don't really want it to contain too much logic. I would like to just validate the event and then forward the mime data to another controller-like object who is in charge of the actual processing logic.

I found this more problematic then expected for a number or reasons.

Who has ownership of the `QMimeData` object? The `QDropEvent`? If so when is the event deleted? The `QDropEvent` is probably scheduled for deletion by Qt, therefore the life time of the mime data has to be considered limited to the `dropEvent()` method. 
Well, I can then just make a copy of the mime data and pass it along. But unfortunately `QMimeData` has no copy constructor or assignment....

Did I get things right so far?
How can I deal with this situation?
Am I trying to fight the framework here or there is a canonical way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the `QMimeData` object forward? You could just pass the data inside the `QMimeData` object. And even if you do have to pass the `QMimeData` object, why do you have to copy it? Surely this data becomes obsolete after the drop event.

Comment: I am in a situation where the user can drop something in different places, and this should lead to the same effect if the dropped object is the same. Therefore I am looking for a way to centralise the processing of the associated data. Does that make sense?

Comment: So process it, why do you have to copy the `QMimeData` object?

Comment: Just to further clarify. Unpacking the `QMimeData` object would certainly work (is what I'm doing right now), but I have to duplicate code. I would like to unpack data and respond accordingly in one single place.

Comment: So create a class or whatever with a function, where you pass this `QMimeData*` as an argument, then process the data inside it, and then do what you have to. You don't have to copy the `QMimeData` object.

Comment: Thanks, good idea.